# binary operator '==' cannot be applied in swift 3

Tags: swift3

In Swift 3 I'm getting a  error when I try to compare two items.

```
    var userData = NSDictionary()




 if !(self.userData.count == 0) && (self.userData["user_status"] == "1") {

                }
```

The error says: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?; and 'String'

What is the correct way to do this in Swift 3?

Comment: I've written maybe 20 lines of swift in my time, but the problem is clearly that your trying to compare 2 different types and swift has no idea how to do that.

Comment: yup i'm trying to compare NSDictionary and string . Here i'm getting error:  "(self.userData["user_status"] == "1") "

Comment: What does self.userData["user_status"] return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
var userData = [String : String]()
userData["user_status"] = "1"
if !(userData.count == 0) && (userData["user_status"] == "1") {
// do something here
print ("hello")
}
```

Comment: The data might be coming in from something he doesn't have direct control over. Please see the duplicate sticky above